# destroying box2d joints from a copied set

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am trying to make a method (destroyWeldJoint) that destroys weldjoints from a copied set. The joints were originally created in another method (createWeldJoint). The reason I am using trying to destroy the weldjoints in another method is because I am calling createWeldJoint in the update method and I would want to avoid trying to change the set while enumerating it. Please see the code below:

createWeldJoint:

```
-(void) createWeldJoint {

// using the iterator pos over the set
std::set<BodyPair *>::iterator pos;

for(pos = bodiesForJoints.begin(); pos != bodiesForJoints.end(); ++pos)
{

    b2WeldJointDef      weldJointDef;

    BodyPair            *bodyPair = *pos;
    b2Body              *bodyA = bodyPair->bodyA;
    b2Body              *bodyB = bodyPair->bodyB;


    weldJointDef.Initialize(bodyA,
                            bodyB,
                            bodyA->GetWorldCenter());
    weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*) world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);

    // Free the structure we allocated earlier.
    free(bodyPair);

    // Remove the entry from the set.
    //bodiesForJoints.erase(pos);

}

// copy of bodiesForJoints
std::set<BodyPair *> bodiesForJointsCopy(bodiesForJoints.begin(), bodiesForJoints.end());

bodiesForJoints.clear();

}
```

destroyWeldJoint:

```
- (void) destroyWeldJoint    {
std::set<BodyPair *>::iterator pos;

for(pos = bodiesForJointsCopy.begin(); pos != bodiesForJointsCopy.end(); ++pos)
{

    BodyPair            *bodyPair = *pos;
    b2Body              *bodyA = bodyPair->bodyA;
    b2Body              *bodyB = bodyPair->bodyB;

    // weldjoint should be destroyed here


    // Free the structure we allocated earlier.
    free(bodyPair);

}    
}
```

How can I destroy the weldjoint (in createWeldJoint) in the destroyWeldJoint method?

Comment: @Nick: how can I destroy the weldjoint (in createWeldJoint) in the destroyWeldJoint method

Comment: When you do this, weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*) world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef); is weldJoint your only reference to the joint?, because you are overwriting it with each iteration.

Comment: @Nick: yes. But the weldjoints consists of bodyPairs which are stored in the bodiesForJoints. Thats why I made a copy of  bodiesForjoints, I thought destroying the bodyPairsor something through the copy could destroy the joint. The bodiesForJoints was declared as std::set<BodyPair *> bodiesForJoints;

Comment: @Nick: I made a contact listener that takes the bodyPair and when two bodies touch and stores them in bodiesForJoints.